# Use Absolute path for ClassLoader getResourceAsStream()

Tags: java, classpath, classloader, absolute-path

I am trying to use ClassLoader getResourceAsStream()

My Direcory structure is like below:

```
Project1

 -src
  -main
   -java
  -webapp
   -WEB-INF
-MYLOC
-someprops.properties
```

For `classloader.getResourceAsStream("MYLOC/someprops.properties")` works fine.

But now I have to move the properties file outside of the .war, like in `C:\someprops.properties`

But, `classloader.getResourceAsStream("C:\someprops.properties")` does not work.
Can it not use an absolute path?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have a native file path then you don't need to use `getResourceAsStream`, just create a `FileInputStream` in the normal way.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\someprops.properties");
try {
  props.load(in);
} finally {
  in.close();
}
```

(you may want to wrap the `FileInputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream` if the file is large)

Answer (score 2):

The method `classloader.getResourceAsStream` looks up resources on the classpath. If you want to load your `someprops.properties` file with `classloader.getResourceAsStream` then add it to your classpath. Otherwise, if this is a properties file, you could always use the [Properties.load](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) method.

Comment: Ok got that part, but the loading of resource is done in another jar file not owned by me so I do not have access to how they load the file but I can only change the locations of the file as required and the path to someprops.properties is with my war