# How to load the class with full absolute path

Tags: java, asmx

This code works only for the class in the same package. I need to load the file from absolute path like c:/home/lpl/asm/hello.class
Any one please help me do this

```
InputStream in=ASMHelloWorld.class.getResourceAsStream("/aasm/ClassModificationDemo.class");
ClassReader classReader=new ClassReader(in);
```

Answer (score 1):

To load a file from an absolute path:

```
String path = "c:/home/lpl/asm/hello.class";
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(in);
```

Obviously hardcoding the path like this, would seriously restrict portability, so the `path` should be obtained from a command line parameter, user input, a properties file etc.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want this? If you do something like that you disable the ability to use the program on a different computer, unless you recreate that folder structure.

Seems like a duplicate question to me, just with a different file: [Use Absolute path for ClassLoader getResourceAsStream()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127017/use-absolute-path-for-classloader-getresourceasstream)